# CommonDataKinds.Phone.NORMALIZED_NUMBER reverses the string

Tags: android, normalization, android-contacts, phone-number

I wanted to read the normalized numbers from the contactbook in Android and this for I used this code:

```
ContentResolver cr = currentActivity.getContentResolver();

    Cursor cur = cr.query(ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI,
            null, null, null, null);
    //Are contacts in the book?
    if (cur.getCount() > 0) {
        while (cur.moveToNext()) {  //Still contacts to save?
            //Does he have at least one telephone number?
            if (Integer.parseInt(cur.getString(cur.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts.HAS_PHONE_NUMBER))) > 0) {


                String id   = cur.getString( cur.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts._ID) );
                String name = cur.getString( cur.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME) );
                ArrayList<String> numbers = new ArrayList<String>();
                ArrayList<String> normalizedNumbers = new ArrayList<String>();
                Log.e("Contactbook", "New Contacts: " + name);

                //Read numbers:
                Cursor pCur = cr.query(
                        ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI,
                        null,
                        ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTACT_ID +" = ?",
                        new String[]{id}, null);
                while (pCur.moveToNext()) {

                    if(!numbers.contains(pCur.getString(
                            pCur.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER)
                    ))) {
                        numbers.add(pCur.getString(
                                pCur.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER)));
                        normalizedNumbers.add(pCur.getString(
                                pCur.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NORMALIZED_NUMBER)));
                        allReadNumbers.add( numbers.get(numbers.size()  - 1) );
                        Log.e("Contactbook", "Number: " + numbers.get(numbers.size() - 1));
                        Log.e("Contactbook", "normalized: " + normalizedNumbers.get(normalizedNumbers.size() - 1));
                    }
                }
                contacts.add(new Contact(numbers, name ) );
                pCur.close();
            }
        }
    }
```

This works fine for reading numbers, but strangely it doesn't give the normalized numbers based on [documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.html#NORMALIZED_NUMBER). Instead it simply reverses the number string.

**Example:**

```
Number: 01602212855
normalized: 55821220610
```

What could cause this bug? Is it even save to assume you would be given a normalized number every time, or should I normalize it myself? If so, which function would be the best for it, based on [PhoneNumberUtils](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/telephony/PhoneNumberUtils.html#normalizeNumber%28java.lang.String%29)
I guess it would be `formatNumberToE164(String phoneNumber, String defaultCountryIso)`, but what would I have to us as `defaultCountryIso` ?

**Edit:** I just found out that I can't use `formatNumberToE164(String phoneNumber, String defaultCountryIso)` because it requires a higher API level than I use at the moment.

Comment: which API level do you need? Maybe you can use PhoneNumberUtils.formatNumber.

Comment: @Nerethar No, it doesn't work, it just provides me with the same that I put into the function.